# Passing uniform webservices through Camel

Tags: web-services, routes, cxf, apache-camel

I'm contemplating using Camel for my project and would like to know if it's feasable or camel is not a good choice.
I need multiple clients running same exact application to exchange information via web services (CXF or AXIS).  The exchange will go through a central hub that will do a content based routing from one client to the other and will also log this communication in the database.  The hub will also route one client's response to another when the responses come in.  There could be a large amount of these exchanges going on from multiple clients.
The webservices are exactly the same so I don't need to integrate different systems.
I just need a routing mechanism and something that would control volume.  Also ease of calling/accepting web service calls is important.
We are a Java/JBoss shop.
Is Camel a fitting solution for this problem or is it an overkill or is there anything else that would fit this requirement better?
I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you
Nadia

Answer (score 2):

Yeah Camel can sit as this hub and route messages.

It support the EIP patterns
http://camel.apache.org/eip

There is plenty of components related to HTTP and WS
http://camel.apache.org/cxf
http://camel.apache.org/http
http://camel.apache.org/jetty
http://camel.apache.org/cxf
http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

And here is a little CXF proxy example
http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html

PS: There is a apache-camel tag which most people use for Camel questions