# Using Apache Cammel as a Broker for WS

Tags: apache-camel, esb

Does anyone know how is the code when using apache cammel lib in my webapp to work as a broker for a WS? Is that even possible? I am doing an ESB and I would like to use cammel to help me to 'deploy' on-demand Web Services from my ERP and all other systems in a webapp, having a unique point of connection (avoiding to create a spiderweb).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902993/passing-uniform-webservices-through-camel

Answer (score 0):

see this example about how CXF can be used to proxy a web service

http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html